# calculating expected gains.

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory

A game costs  \$100 to play. 
Toss a coin repeatedly, and win \$1 if you get heads for the first time, \$2 if you get heads both of the first two times, \$4 all of the first three times, \$8, and so on. But the game stops if you withdraw, or get tails.

You decide to withdraw after the K-th round, if you manage to keep rolling heads that long. Calculate expected winnings for each k.

K=1, E[W]= (0.5*0) + (0.5*1) = 0.5

K=2, E[W]= (0.5*0) + (0.25*1) + (0.25*2) = 0.75

K=3, E[W]= (0.5*0) + (0.25*1) + (0.125*2) + (0.125*4) = 1.

$\vdots$

I can't understand how the expected gains was calculated.